# PowerShell: How to substitute array value into regex expression within Where-Object -MATCH

Tags: powershell, regex

I am having trouble getting a string value from an array to insert into the regex expression in the `-match` condition of `Where-Object` below.

```
$ordArr = @("001", "005", "002", "007")

for ($i = 0; $i -le $ordArr.Length) {
  get-childitem -file -recurse |
    where-object {$_.BaseName -match "^$ordArr[$i].*$"} |
      ForEach-Object {echo $_}

  $i = ($i + 2)
}
```

If I am to enter `$ordArr[$i]` by itself (i.e. call it outside the presence of the `Where-Object` function, it returns the expected string values.

I have also tried

- `... -match "^${ordArr[$i]}.*$ ... "`
- `... -match "^${ordArr[$[tick mark]{i[tick mark]}]}.*$ ... "`

and other misc. combinations using tick markets and braces. However, I cannot get the string value from the `$ordArr` to substituted into the command.

Depending upon the combination of braces and tick marks, it either returns nothing or everything. Also, if I am to manually enter `001` from the `$ordArr` into the regex expression, `... -match "^001.*$" ...`, then it will return the files I expect.

So, how can I insert a value from an array into the regex condition within `Where-Object ... -match ...`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex pattern does not interpolate the string like you intend.

`"^$ordArr[$i].*$"}` results in `^001 005 002 007[0].*$`

You have to use the **subexpression operator** `$()` if you want to use expressions like calculations (`$int1 + $int2`), member access (`$something.Path`), index access (`$array[1]`), etc. within another expression like a String.

In your case you have to put your `$ordArr[$i]` into a subexpression:

```powershell
"^$($ordArr[$i]).*$"
```

See: [MSFT: Subexpression operator $( )](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#subexpression-operator--)

Furthermore you should avoid using `Get-ChildItem` for the same location within a `for` or `foreach` loop.
In your example you call Get-ChildItem recursively 4 times for the same items.

### My suggestion

My suggestion is to define a combined regex pattern to have a single one instead of looping several times over an array to build a pattern.
This is much faster than other approaches.

```powershell
$ordArr = @('001', '005', '002', '007')

# build a combined regex pattern 
#   this time we don't need a subexpression operator, since we don't access any member or index from $_
$regexPattern = ($ordArr | ForEach-Object { "^$_.*$" }) -join '|'

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.BaseName -match  $regexPattern 

    # as alternative and to avoid saving anything to the automatic variable $matches (-> better performance)
    # but not idiomatic Powershell:
    # [regex]::IsMatch($_.BaseName, $regexPattern)
}
```

Comment: I was not able to adapt your solution to my needs (and I am not yet skilled with the role of `-join`) so I unable to mark it as an answer - though it may be. Your comment, `"^$($ordArr[$i]).*$"` was useful as I was able to adapt it and insert it into `Get-Childitem` and eliminate the need for `Where-Object` altogether. So, thank you for your guidance. I will add `-join` to my list of skills that I need to develop.

Comment: I am not adding this as a self-answer as it doesn't solve the problem I asked. However, here is the workaround solution to my overall problem" `for ($i=0; $i -lt $ordArr.Length) {get-childitem "$($ordArr[$i])*" -file -recurse | foreach-object {$path=$_.DirectoryName+"\"; $base=$_.BaseName; $ext=$_.Extension; $newbase="$($ordArr[$($i+1)]) $base"; $newfile="$path$newbase$ext"; mv $_.FullName $newfile}; $i+=2}` where `$ordArr=@("001","005")` is a paired array where the even entries represent the start of the filename of interest and the paired odd entries are the new numbers I wish to prefix.

Comment: @Brian The operator `-Join` combines all elements of an array/collection and uses the delimiter you have defined. In my example I joined all elements using the regex "or" operator `|` as delimiter. But to be honest, your mentioned workaround doesn't fit your initial question.